# Suggestion generating and dividing records in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to generate all combination of codes for that array

```
"2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "8", "9", "Q", "W", "R", "T", "Y", "P", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "X", "C", "V", "B", "M"
```

Valid code must have 25 simbols, and have 5 segments separate by "-"

For example

34267-89QWR-TYPDF-GHJKX-CVBMG

43267-89QWR-TYPDF-GHJKX-CVBMG

After generate each of combination script must instert to table that code. I try to use that but it only generate all combination of that array but not codes with 25 simbols. Please help me

```
<?php

require 'config.php';

function pc_permute($items, $perms = array()) {
    if (empty($items)) { 
        $result = join('', $perms);

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO gen (code) VALUES ('$result');") or die ('Wystąpił błąd w zapytaniu lub kod nie zostal dodany.');

    } else {
        for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
             $newitems = $items;
             $newperms = $perms;
             list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
             array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
             pc_permute($newitems, $newperms);
         }
    }
}

$arr = array("2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "8", "9", "Q", "W", "R", "T", "Y", "P", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "X", "C", "V", "B", "M");

pc_permute($arr);

?>
```

If You could help me i will be very happy.

PS. Please add statement In one sement can't be 5 the same simbols

For example:

AAAAB-AAAAB-AAAAB-AAAAB-AAAAB **GOOD COMBINATION**

AAAAA-AAAAA-AAAAA-AAAAA-AAAAA **BAD COMBINATION**

AAAAA-AAAAB-AAAAB-AAAAB-AAAAB **BAD COMBINATION**

Answer (score 3):

```
function generateId($arr, $max) { //$max sets the amount of characters you want it to be
    $results = '';
    for($i = 0;$i < $max;$i++) {
        if($i % 5 == 0 && $i > 0) { //appends '-' every 5 characters
            $results .= '-';
        }
        $rand = rand(0, (count($arr) - 1));
        $results .= $arr[$rand];
    }
    if(preg_match('/(.)\\1{4}/', $results)) return generateId($arr, $max); //checks if 5 characters repeat
    else return $results;
}

$id = generateId($arr, 25); //pass your array of characters as argument
```

Comment: Thaks for reply but i have a suggestion. Could You add verification is that code include 25 symbols or 29 symbols with separator? In some tests Your script give me code with 4 symbols in one segments. For example:

3WXQG-3H6Q-M9BYQ-G7HJW-2Y92B

Comment: `count($arr)` needs to be `count($arr)-1` in `$rand = rand(0, count($arr));` -> `$rand = rand(0, count($arr)-1);`.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that and changed it

Comment: That 4 symbols in some was caused by the thing I missed that Sean just mentioned. Because rand(0, count($arr)) creates the potential to try to access $arr[25] which doesn't exist. Creating the blank characters in some. The array's actual indices being 0-24

Comment: Realy Realy thanks :) Now i must add verification of each of code because i don't need double of the same code. What is the best method to elimate the same record? I try to use

 `$check_code = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $first WHERE code = '$result' LIMIT 1"));
 
 
 //Jeżeli nie dodanie go do bazy
 if ($check_code[0] < 1) {
 
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO gen (code) VALUES ('$result');") or die ('Wystąpił błąd w zapytaniu lub kod nie zostal dodany.');}`

Comment: You don't need to. The odds of a repeat are like 1 in a trillion. But if you're dead set. You just check if the value exists in your database before inserting it.

Comment: I was curious so I looked further, the actual odds are closer to 1 in 500 trillion.